# how to place a text in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm want to put text in the top left corner, how I do it in this code?

[image: this how I want to put the text].

Thanks for the help!

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Home-page',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home:MyHomePage(title: 'home-page',),

    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);     
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int counter = 0;
  int f,e;
  int n=20;
  void _updateLabels(int init, int end, int u) {
    setState(() {
      f = init;
      e = end;
      n=0;
      n=e-f;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),   
      body: Center(     
        child: Column(       
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[

           DoubleCircularSlider(100, 0, 20,
          height: 260.0,
          width: 260.0,
          primarySectors: 6,
          secondarySectors: 24,
          baseColor: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
          handlerOutterRadius: 12.0,
          onSelectionChange:_updateLabels ,
          child: Center(
                child: Text('$n',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 36.0, color: Colors.white))),
          ),
          ],
        ),
      ),   
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove the `Center` widget as the child of the `Scaffold` because it will center all it's contents, thus not allowing the text you want to be aligned on the top left corner.
2. Remove the `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center` from the `Column` as this property will align all the contents of the column to the center vertically.
3. Add your Text widget as the first child of the column and align it to the left using the style property of the `Text` widget
4. Wrap your `CircularIndicator` with an `Expanded` Widget along with a `Center` Widget.

See code snippet below for the scaffold:

```
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.green,
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Text"),
  ),
  body: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      Text("Test", textAlign: TextAlign.left, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
      Expanded(
        child: Center(
          child: DoubleCircularSlider(
            100,
            0,
            20,
            height: 260.0,
            width: 260.0,
            primarySectors: 6,
            secondarySectors: 24,
            baseColor: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
            handlerOutterRadius: 12.0,
            onSelectionChange: _updateLabels,
            child: Center(
                child: Text('$n',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 36.0, color: Colors.white))),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```